# How to add key and value pairs to new empty dictionary using for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to create a new dictionary from a list with dictionary values.

```
debts_list = [{'amount': 123.46, 'id': 0}, {'amount': 100, 'id': 1}, {'amount': 4920.34, 'id': 2}, {'amount': 12938, 'id': 3}, {'amount': 9238.02, 'id': 4}]
```

Here is my for loop.

```
new_debt_dic = {}
for i in debts_list:
    for k, v in i.items():
        new_debt_dic[k] = v
```

Problem here is that I'm only getting the last key and value added. Output is {'amount': 9238.02, 'id': 4} when I want to get all the values. I tried using setdefault but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. What other libraries/solutions can this be solved with?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, dictionary keys are unique. If you assign a value to the same key again, it gets overwritten. Example :

```py
dct = {}
dct["key"] = "value"
print(dct)
dct["key"] = "value2"
print(dct)
```

Output :

```
{"key": "value"}
{"key": "value2"}
```

The only option you have is to create a list of amounts and a list of ids:

```py
new_debt_dic = {"amounts": [], "ids": []}
for i in debts_list:
    new_debt_dic["amounts"].append(i["amount"])
    new_debt_dic["ids"].append(i["id"])
print(new_debt_dic)
```

Output :

```py
{"amounts": [123.46, 100, ...], "ids": [0, 1, ...]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each value of `debts_list` is dictionary with only 2 key-value pairs, where the keys are `amount` or  `id`. I think you meant to use the `id` as your keys - if so, you should use the following:

```
new_debt_dic = {}    
for d in debts_list:
        new_debt_dic[d['id']] = d['amount']
```

Comment: I still need the string 'amount' and 'id' as keys though.